# Image Viewer - Automatically fill window with image

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, 11.04, image-viewers, eog

When I maximise an Image Viewer window, the picture stays the same size. In the view options none of them seem to make the image just fill the window.

I can zoom in but that is quite irritating as I have to compare several pictures in a folder and it forgets that I zoomed in when I return to a picture.

Is there anyway to change the default behaviour? Or perhaps there is a different program I should be using?

Note:
This is for my work computer which will be sticking with 11.10 for at least another month, but any 12.04 specific advice would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use [feh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/feh) instead.  `feh -ZXrF ./` results in a full screen image of all subfolders recursively and you can navigate with the arrow keys.  Change to `feh -ZXrFD 5 ./` to auto-advance after 5 seconds.

Comment: Just realised I can do full screen with Image Viewer which solves my problem, but I like your solution much better!

Comment: thank you for the full screen idea. You should submit it as an answer, and I would up vote it.

Comment: @Anake how do you do it using Image Viewer/eog?